# Private repository on bitbucket

Tags: composer-php, bitbucket

I am creating a plugin on bitbucket private repo. Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project/my-plugin",
  "repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:project/my-plugin.git"        
  }
 ]
}
```

But I am getting following error on "composer require project/my-plugin:dev-master"

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1
    - The requested package ephyre/voxilo-cakephp-teams-plugin could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `composer.json` file you pasted is from your plugin. `repositories` section needs to go to your project `composer.json` file, not to your plugin.